# MYSQL - Subquery devuelve más de una fila

Tags: mysql

La siguiente consulta me arroja el error:

> "#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row "

```
SELECT player_id, (SELECT points FROM history_ataque

WHERE fecha > '2018-09-04'
GROUP BY player_id
ORDER BY points DESC, fecha DESC) as hoy,

(SELECT points FROM history_ataque
WHERE fecha > '2018-09-03'
GROUP BY player_id
ORDER BY points DESC, fecha DESC) as ayer

FROM history_ataque
```

Quiero obtener de cada player_id, los puntos de hoy y de mañana, para restarlos y obtener su diferencia. Y ordenarlos por esta diferencia.

Tabla:

idrow
rank
**player_id**
points
es
**fecha**

11115
998
**552**
1956
72
**2018-09-03 10:51:39**

15210
974
**552**
2068
72
**2018-09-04 06:00:02**

19305
974
**552**
2068
72
**2018-09-04 06:27:40**

23400
974
**552**
2068
72
**2018-09-04 07:00:01**

12212
858
**3165**
2560
72
**2018-09-03 10:51:39**

16307
852
**3165**
2565
72
**2018-09-04 06:00:02**

20402
852
**3165**
2565
72
**2018-09-04 06:27:40**

24497
852
**3165**
2565
72
**2018-09-04 07:00:01**

Comment: En un campo de `SELECT` la consulta debe devolver un único registro. ¿Podrías exportar la tabla y sus datos en forma de SQL y no en tabla de texto para facilitarnos las pruebas? Gracias.

Comment: Tus subquerys pueden devolver n registros pues comparas las fechas con mayor que, por lo que traera todos los registros que sean mayores que. Debes hacerlo con igual y con formaters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que lo que intentas es sumar todos los puntos del jugador de dos días, hoy y ayer, pero en realidad estás sacando todos los puntos de cada registro que hay de dicho jugador

Yo probaría con esta consulta si que quieres sacar los puntos de esos dos días:

```
SELECT history_ataque.player_id, hoy.points as hoy_points, ayer.points as ayer_points
FROM history_ataque
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT MAX(points) as points, player_id
   FROM history_ataque
   WHERE fecha > '2018-09-03' and fecha < '2018-09-05'
   GROUP BY player_id) as hoy
ON history_ataque.player_id = hoy.player_id 
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT MAX(points) as points, player_id
   FROM history_ataque
   WHERE fecha > '2018-09-02' and fecha < '2018-09-04'
   GROUP BY player_id) as ayer
ON history_ataque.player_id = ayer.player_id
```

Comment: Muchas gracias pero no es exactamente eso. Los puntos son acumulables, es decir si un día tiene varios registros de puntos a diferentes horas, solo vale el registrado con la ultima hora. Despues de esto lo que quiero conseguir es la diferencia que hay de puntos entre el último registro de ayer  y el último de hoy de cada jugador. EJ: El resultado del player 552 sería 2068 - 1956 = 112 puntos. Todo lo demás no me sirve.

Comment: Ok, los puntos son los totales pero ¿siempre serán más cada vez? ¿o puede pasar que pierda puntos?

Comment: Nunca pierde, siempre suman o quedan igual como el dia anterior.

Comment: Cambia el SUM por MAX y ya lo tienes.Te actualizo la respuesta

Comment: La tuya ya parece funcionar bien y solo 3 segundos pero con un par de cambios, he agregado en el select "hoy.points-ayer.points as diferencia" y al final para eliminar duplicados y ordenar "GROUP BY player_id ORDER BY diferencia DESC" Gracias.

Comment: Encantado de ayudar

Comment: Javi, una pequeña consulta a parte pero en relación a esto. Si quiero sacar el nombre del player que se encuentra en otra tabla y que está relacionado asi (history_ataque.player_id = jugadores.id) como lo haría? he probado a crear un WHERE con esa condición debajo del ultimo ON y en el from he agregado la tabla jugadores pero me da error.

Comment: Pon la consulta completa aunque igual es mejor ponerlo otra pregunta, no sé exactamente cómo encaja en las normas de stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Prueba usando esto:

```
select 

    t1.player_id, t1.date fecha, t1.points points, t2.points, prev_day_points, t1.points-t2.points points_difference
from
    (select player_id, date(fecha) date, max(points) points from history_ataque group by player_id,fecha) t1
    inner join (select player_id, date(fecha) date, max(points) points from history_ataque group by player_id,fecha) t2
    on t1.player_id=t2.player_id and t1.date = t2.date+interval 1 day

where # opcional
    t1.date = date(now())
```

Comment: Haciendo un `group by player_id,fecha` no agrupas nada pues da un registro por cada registro.

Comment: El group by si me hace falta puesto que la tabla tiene varios registros por día de un mismo usiario, de todas formas ya lo he agregado y parece que funciona aunque tengo que revisarlo mas detenidamente, el problema mas gordo que le veo es que me tarda en ejecutar la consulta 20 segundos, es inviable, no se si es por mi tabla o por la consulta. Voy a ver las respuestas de los demás compañeros para salir de dudas.

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro de que funcione pues no puedo probarlo pero creo que esto resuelve el problema (si no es así dilo y lo borro).

```
SELECT Today.player_id, Today.hoy, Yesterday.ayer
FROM 
    (SELECT A.player_id, A.points as hoy
    FROM history_ataque A
    JOIN (
        SELECT player_id, MAX(fecha) as ultima
        FROM history_ataque
        WHERE date(fecha) = date('2018-09-04 00:00:00')
        GROUP BY player_id) B 
    ON B.player_id = A.player_id AND A.fecha = B.ultima) Today
JOIN 
    (SELECT C.player_id, C.points as ayer
    FROM history_ataque C
    JOIN (
        SELECT player_id, MAX(fecha) as ultima
        FROM history_ataque
        WHERE date(fecha) = date('2018-09-03 00:00:00')
        GROUP BY player_id) D 
    ON D.player_id = C.player_id AND D.fecha = C.ultima) Yesterday
ON Today.player_id = Yesterday.player_id;
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'D.fecha' in 'on clause', estoy buscando a ver que se te pasó :P

Comment: Es C.fecha = D,ultima que lo lie :(

Comment: Gracias ahora si pero me tarda 25 segundos la consulta, me voy a quedar con la respuesta de otro compañero. Muchas gracias de todas formas.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta esto:

```
SELECT player_id, (SELECT SUM(points) points FROM history_ataque t1

WHERE fecha > '2018-09-04' AND t1.player_id=t0.player_id
GROUP BY player_id
ORDER BY points DESC, fecha DESC) as hoy,

(SELECT SUM(points) points FROM history_ataque t2
WHERE fecha > '2018-09-03' AND t2.player_id=t0.player_id
GROUP BY player_id
ORDER BY points DESC, fecha DESC) as ayer

FROM history_ataque t0
```

Comment: Esta consulta tiene buena pinta, carga muy rápida pero no es lo que necesito. No quiero sumar los registros de puntos de cada día, solo coger el ultimo registro de puntos del día y restarlo al ultimo del día anterior.